# How do I Implement Docusign Connect API authentication with the Include X509 Certificate option checked?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, docusignapi

I have three questions. First, what is the difference between Sign Message with X509 Certificate, and Include X509 Certificate?

Second How do I implement **Sign Message with X509 Certificate**?
Third How do I implement **Include X509 Certificate**

I am using a Rails 4 app as my Connect API endpoint.

I tried getting this information from many places, but unable to find something substantial. I tried taking help from the [docusign connect guide](https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/pdf/connect-guide.pdf) as well.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Signing with x509 will digitally sign the notification (xml), include x509 in certificate is specific to SOAP publishing, and will include the (same) x509 in the SOAP header if you are using the SOAP method.
2. There are multiple ways to use either methods. The first is simply set up a Connect configuration at the account level in your DocuSign account and tick the box for either. However, they are mutually exclusive. This will publish your requested events for every DocuSign envelope sent, regardless of source (API or WebApp). The second is if using the DocuSign API to set your events per envelope (as opposed to account wide). This is done with the eventNotification parameter in your envelope creation call, the REST guide can be found [here](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/#definition-eventNotification)

Comment: The main purpose that I want to use the authentication is to secure my endpoint. Could you please tell me how do I secure and restrict unsigned requests to my endpoint by using x509 authentication?

Comment: did you succeed to set up X509 , can't find any proper documentation on how to proceed

Comment: This should help https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-securing-connect-webhook-listener/